# No buildable Go source files in folder

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

**Update**: Changed `${workspaceRoot}` to `${workspaceRoot}/project_folder` to get it to work.

---

I am just starting to learning Go and want to run it from Visual Studio Code.

I have this simple program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

I installed the Go extension from the marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lukehoban.Go

I also got the Delve debugger from here using `go get`: https://github.com/derekparker/delve

To try and run the code, I do this in Visual Studio Code:

- I click on my file with the above code `main.go`
- Go to the `Debug` tab
- Click `Launch` (after generating the `launch.json` file)

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "remotePath": "",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally, I get this error:

```
can't load package: package github.com/mo: no buildable Go source files in C:\Users\Fazil\Documents\Workspace\Go\src\github.com\mo
exit status 1
```

Am I supposed to include something else? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Compile on the command line.

Comment: Also, make sure that the GOPATH and GOROOT environment variables are correct.

Comment: Turns out I had to add my folder in the 'launch.json' file. So I changed `${workspaceRoot}` to `${workspaceRoot}/folder`. Thank you both, however. I was able to learn how to compile from command line and more about the environment variables for Go.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already got it working by changing your working folder to the actual project folder, but here's the clue that should have helped

```
can't load package: package github.com/mo
```

github.com/mo is your username, not the project folder - Go is trying to run one folder up. You should always see `github.com/mo/PROJECT`